# Accessing nested array element in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array:

```
aFrmsTbFields.push(["e7" , ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]]);
aFrmsTbFields.push(["e8", ["ddd", "eee", "fff"]]);
aFrmsTbFields.push(["e9", ["xxx", "yyy"]]);
```

I want to get `["xxx", "yyy"]` array by `e9` identifier.

How I can do it in JavaScript?

I have tried:

```
aXXXYYY = aFrmsTbFields["e9"];
```

But it doesn't work. I already know that arrays in JS are a bit diffrent than arrays in PHP.

I could create object, but im afraid I'm too bad in Javascript to handle them. I'm using `array.forEach()` a lot and I need to run something like this later:

```
aXXXYYY.forEach(...) // loop on ["xxx", "yyy"] array
```

Comment: Use an object instead of array: `var fields = { "e7": ["aaa", ...], "e8": ["ddd", ...], "e9": ["xxx", ...] }; var e9 = fields["e9"];`

Comment: You might find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) of interest.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `filter` method on `Array` object:

```
aFrmsTbFields.filter(function(arr) { return arr[0] === 'e9' })[0][1]
```

You may even wrap this into a function:

```
var findByFirst = function(arrayOfArrays, item) {
    return arrayOfArrays.filter(function(a) { return a[0] === item; })[0][1];
};
```

How it works, first filter returns only these array elements for which predicate returns `true` in our case arrays that have 'e9' as 0th element.
Then we get first of these array (we expecct only one here) in our case `['eq', ["foo", "bar"]]` then we access second element of that array by using `[1]` index, that will be `["foo", "bar"]`.

As other answers suggested object whould be much more useful here:

```
var obj = { 
  'e1': ['a', 'b'],
  // ... 
};

obj['e1'] // returns ['a', 'b']
```

Thanks Rick Hitchcock for spotting error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you want to use an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

```
aFrmsTbFields.e9 = ['xxx', 'yyy'];
console.log(aFrmsTbFields.e9);
```

**Edit:** There's no such thing as being "too bad" at a language. Just means you have more to learn. If you absolutely need to iterate through an object, you can use a `for..in` loop.

```
for (var fieldName in aFrmsTbFields) {
  // fieldName == e7 or e8 or e9 etc.
  var array = aFrmsTbFields[fieldName]; // ['xxx', 'yyy'];
}
```